# Cannot create new Organisation Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops-services

I am pretty new to Azure DevOps coming from a GitHub and BitBucket background.  I managed to create a an org and a project which I subsequently deleted with the idea of re-creating it.  After the sign-in page I get this screen

[image]

and every time I hit continue I get presented with exactly the same form.  No error messages, there is just nothing that happens.

Not sure if I managed to corrupt my account by initially deleting everything in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation has resolved itself.  I am assuming it was just an "eventually consistent" issue.